# Using Computed Properties inside Methods in vueJs

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I'm trying to create a shuffle function in vue.js. So, for this i created a computed properties and then i call a method. but it doesn't working. I've created two more function 'add' and 'remove' these two working fine except 'shuffle'.

Throwing an error: **Uncaught TypeError: this.moveIndex is not a function**

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    tasks: [1,8,9],
    nextNum: 10
  },
  computed: {
    moveIndex: function(array){
      var currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex, tempVal;
      for(var i = currentIndex - 1; i > 0; i--){
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        tempVal = array[i];
        array[i] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = tempVal;
      }
      return array;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    randIndex: function(){
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.tasks.length);
    },
    add: function(){
      this.tasks.splice(this.randIndex(),0,this.nextNum++)
    },
    remove: function(){
      this.tasks.splice(this.randIndex(),1)
    },
    shuffle: function(){
      var arr = this.tasks;
      arr = this.moveIndex(arr)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.bar-enter-active, .bar-leave-active{
  transition: all 1s;
}
.bar-enter, .bar-leave-to{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px)
}
.bar-move{
  transition: transform 1s 
}
.numbers{
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

 <div id="root">
  <button @click="add">Add</button>
  <button @click="remove">Remove</button>
  <button @click="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
  <transition-group name="bar" tag="div">
   <span v-for="task in tasks" :key="task" class="numbers">{{task}}</span>
  </transition-group>
 </div>
```

Comment: You cannot call computed properties as a function. They are properties (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) . If you want a function move it to the methods and you can call it as such.

Comment: I cannot see a single reason why `moveIndex` would make sense as a computed. Put it into methods.

Comment: Also this a classic case of an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) are just getter functions that return a value and are dependent on other reactive properties.

**1.** Your computed property `moveIndex` is just modifying an array data property i.e `this.tasks`. So just use a method instead.

**2.** You are trying to directly modify an item of the `this.tasks` array using index. Vue cannot detect [such array modifications](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

So use [`this.$set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set) or [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) instead.

Here are the changes:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    tasks: [1, 8, 9],
    nextNum: 10
  },
  methods: {
    randIndex: function() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.tasks.length);
    },
    add: function() {
      this.tasks.splice(this.randIndex(), 0, this.nextNum++);
    },
    remove: function() {
      this.tasks.splice(this.randIndex(), 1);
    },
    shuffle: function() {
      var array = this.tasks;
      var currentIndex = this.tasks.length;
      var randomIndex;
      var tempVal;

      for (var i = currentIndex - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        tempVal = array[i];
        this.$set(array, i, array[randomIndex]);
        this.$set(array, randomIndex, tempVal);
      }
    }
    
  }
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kouqsr91/1/)